Whitebox Tools disappeared in QGIS
Whitebox Tools has disappeared from the Processing Toolbox on QGIS. I've reinstalled etc. but no luck. Could this be due to a recent update glitch?

Have you installed the binaries?  "This plugin provides the QGIS interface with WBT, however it does not include the WBT binary itself. Before using the tools, you will need to download and install them from https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/."

Which OS & version of QGIS are you using? I am on Windows 11/QGIS 3.34.5 and I have the same problem. The "fix" was to revert back to the 1.0.9 plugin (1.1.1 & 1.1.0 both seem to have the same issue).

I no longer release the QGIS plugin for WhiteboxTools with the tool description files. Instead these are automatically generated by communicating with the WhiteboxTools binary file (i.e. the backend). This is a better approach because it means that the available tools and their parameters will always be in step with the backend. However, when you first install the plugin, it does not know where to find your installed WhiteboxTools backend (which you need to install separately) and therefore, there aren't any tool description files generated and the plugin won't appear in the QGIS Processing toolbox. Therefore, after installing the plugin, you must go to the QGIS settings for the toolbox and update the path to the WhiteboxTools executable file (either whitebox_tools.exe or simply whitebox_tools depending on the OS), which will be contained within a WBT folder.

Once you've done this, the plugin should generate the description files (this can take a few minutes) and the plugin will appear in the Processing toolbox. There is a warning to this effect that is issued when you first install the plugin, and the plugin description also describes this process, but I suppose that many users won't necessarily see them causing confusion. My apologies.


Of course, you can also avoid all of this by using the next generation QGIS plugin for Whitebox, called Whitebox Workflows for QGIS, which streamlines the installation process and is built atop the Whitebox Workflows codebase instead, with all the advantages that that offers. It's the solution that I prefer, and I developed both the QGIS plugins and the backends for both WhiteboxTools and Whitebox Workflows.

Keep in mind that there are two plugins related to WhiteboxTools scope:

Whitebox Workflows for QGIS
WhiteboxTools for QGIS

The first one is visible in the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T)

However, the second one is not. To use it, I can suggest using this plugin via Python Console (Ctrl+Alt+P) as follows:
from qgis.utils import plugins
from plugins.wbt_for_qgis.plugin import WbtPlugin

wbt = WbtPlugin()

I am utilizing QGIS 3.34.8-Prizren.

If you are using version 1.10 of the plugin, uninstall it and install version 1.09. That fixed the issue for me. Version 1.10 was released 2 days ago and it looks like it contained a bug of some sort.

The "WhiteboxTools for QGIS" plugin version 1.1.1 was released on Aug 9th, 2024.

The 1.1.1 version has the same issue, at least under Windows. I assume not all OSs are equally affected.

The 1.1.1 and 1.1.0 versions have been rolled back to 1.0.9 - https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/issues/425
